# Help writing out comments and replies

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on creating a comment system for an event plugin I am creating. I have the commenting and replies forms working correctly, I just need help with writing them out to the site. I am on MySql 5.6 so can't use a recursive query.

**Comment Table**

```
id - int
eventid - int
userid - int
content - text
datesaved - datetime
parentid - int
```

**PHP/SQL** What I currently have to display the comments. This doesn't display the replies, that's what I need help with.

```
$commentsql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comm.id as id, comm.eventid as eventid, comm.userid as userid, comm.content as comment, comm.datesaved as date, users.meta_value as fname, users2.meta_value as lname
                                FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cmc_communitybb_event_comments as comm
                                inner join " . $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta as users on comm.userid = users.user_id and users.meta_key = 'first_name'
                                inner join " . $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta as users2 on comm.userid = users2.user_id and users2.meta_key = 'last_name'
                                where comm.eventid=$eventid and comm.parentid is null order by comm.datesaved desc");

foreach ($commentsql as $comment) {
    //code to display comments goes here
}
```

Comment: WordPress already has a commenting system -- see, for example, [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) -- so I'm not sure why you'd go to the effort to build your own.

Comment: This is for custom content, not pages or posts.

Comment: You can use the built-in comment system on custom post types as well.